# function not returning expected result. two sums leetcode

Tags: java

I am doing the two sums problem from leetcode. I understand the below methods is not correct in terms of efficiency. However, I dont understand why it doesnt work.

For the below code, I am not seeing the expected solution of [1,2] when the input is {3,2,4}.I have inculded the result if the print statements below.

Why does the loop break? It doesn't print out the                     System.out.println("result[i]"+result[0]); line.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] myArray= {3,2,4};

    twoSum(myArray, 6);
}   


 public static int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
    int[] result= new int[1];
    for (int i =0;i<nums.length;i++){

        System.out.println("i:"+i);
        System.out.println("nums[i]:"+nums[i]);

        for (int y=i+1;y<nums.length-i; y++){
            System.out.println("y: "+y);
            System.out.println("nums[y]:"+nums[y]);
            int x = nums[i]+nums[y];
            System.out.println("x:"+x);
            if (x==target){
                result[0]=i;
                result[1]=y;
                System.out.println("result[i]"+result[0]);
                System.out.println("result[y]"+result[1]);
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    return result;
}
```

**Result of print statements:**

i:0

nums[i]:3

y: 1

nums[y]:2

x:5

y: 2

nums[y]:4

x:7

i:1

nums[i]:2

i:2

nums[i]:4

Comment: `nums.length-i` - remove `-i`

Comment: removing i leads to error. see below.


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
 at Runner.twoSum(Runner.java:25)
 at Runner.main(Runner.java:9)

Answer (score 2):

Remove -i from this line

```
for (int y=i+1;y<nums.length-i; y++)
```

that is, the correct loop will look like

```
for (int y=i+1;y<nums.length; y++)
```

One more mistake, you have declared array result with the length 1, but you when you are using it, you are going out of bound thus declare array result something like this:

```
int[] result= new int[2];
```

Also you are returning array from twosum function but not storing it in the main function.